# Volley Cache not working

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I am trying to cache the downloaded images on the mainview and display them in the detail view. The way I am testing is as follows: first, I display all images on the gridview and disconnect the Internet and wanted to see cached image on the detail. However, on the detail activity the image is not being displayed.

I am using the following **Volley Singleton** class as follows:

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest {

    private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
    private static Context context;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
        CustomVolleyRequest.context = context;
        this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
        if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
            customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
        }
        return customVolleyRequest;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity Adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    }
  holder.imageView.setImageUrl(imageURL, mImageLoader);
}
```

**Detail Activity**

```
// I have checked and confirmed that the following url is same with the one the main activity
String url = getArguments().getString("image_url");
ImageLoader imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(getContext()).getImageLoader();
mImageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Comment: Your LRU cache is too small, no image can fit on that thats why nothing is cached.

Comment: @Enzokie, in order to hold decent 10 images, what should I suppose to use?

Comment: The ideal size for LRU cache is 1/7th of the Device memory capacity. See the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Volley caching still works, however, your issue here is because of the `NetworkImageView` inside the detail activity, which is different from the `NetworkImageView` inside the main activity, it also needs to load the image successfully one time first. Here, you disconnect Internet before starting to the detail activity.

You can see the logic inside [NetworkImageView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/c3dea925af9b3523e2e01e8b7799e71ef558c1c5/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java#122)

Pay attention to the lines from #122

```
// if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
        if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {...
```

and #134

```
// The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL. Load the new image
        // from the network.
        ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,...
```

---

**UPDATE 2017/02/10**

When the `NetworkImageView` inside detail activity loads the new image from the network (`ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get...`), the method `get` inside [ImageLoader.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/c3dea925af9b3523e2e01e8b7799e71ef558c1c5/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#186) will be called.

See the code:

```
...
final String cacheKey = getCacheKey(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight);
// Try to look up the request in the cache of remote images.
Bitmap cachedBitmap = mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey);
if (cachedBitmap != null) {
    // Return the cached bitmap.
    ImageContainer container = new ImageContainer(cachedBitmap, requestUrl, null, null);
    imageListener.onResponse(container, true);
    return container;
}
...
```

You will find that if the the image views in both activities have the same width and height, then `cacheKey` will be the same too and the `cachedBitmap` will be not null, cached bitmap will be used for the `NetworkImageView` inside detail activity also.

Comment: BNK, I guess the question here is, "Can we load a NetworkImageView container with an image which is cached in another NetworkImageView?". The cache needed in this question is some kind of global hash-map of "url:bitmap", where the url is the key to get the bitmap from the memory. Based on your answer, looks like Volley only caches the image for the NetworkImageView it is loaded the first time only. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: @erolyeniaras I think the bitmap data still cached, please read my updated answer.